# How to have a PDO database(sql server) in php7.2.19 using IIS7 server

Tags: php, sql-server, iis

I'm setting up a database on `sql server` and with `php7.2` in `IIS7`. The problem is that I've inserted the dll files in the php `ext` folder and I have edited my `php.ini`, but the sql did not appear in `PDO` support. What should I do next?

The php is working correctly in IIS7.

Comment: I am not exactly sure where is problem, but can be order of libraries inserted in php.ini, on windows order of libraries in php.ini matter, also did you restart/reload your server after making changes in php.ini?

Comment: Hi, yes i always restart the iis after making changes. but the sql server did not work. Do you have suggestion where will i get the dll files of sql server for php7.2 in iis? Thankyou!

Comment: This was done. I download the microsoft ODBC driver for sql server and sql server works. Thanks